# Copy Files from Multiple Sources to Multiple Destination at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, vbscript

I have written a code to copy all files in a directory using c# to a particluar location.I am calling that exe using a .bat file for this process.

The problem is there are n number of sources and n number of destinations and this batch job at a time only copy files from one location to another one.

Is there any way to copy files through a .bat file or using script or even using .net technology from multiple sources to multiple destination?

Copying file from one location to another is easy but i want to copy files from multiple locations at the same time.

Please help me for making this possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time" - do you want to create a multi-threaded application?

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to copy them in parallel? If those files are on different devices then there is some sense in it, but , if they are on the same drive(doesn't matter whether on HDD, SDD, flash...), then total copying time will be even longer than one-by-one due to constant switching between tasks - most storage devices aren't designed to effectively handle random writes and read.

Comment: Send each copy command out to it's own process. See `Start /?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `class` called `CopyThread` which inherits from the `Thread` `class`. Add `source` and `destination` member to them along with setters. When you create a `CopyThread` object make sure you set its `source` and `destination` values. When you start the thread, it should copy all files from `source` to `destination`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one solution for that,use "command line parameters" to take source and destination path as input to your program and from a batch file call your program multiple times with diffrent parameters. If your sources and destinations are dynamic you have to write small batch program to take inputs for source and destination and call your program with the given inputs as parameters.